# How to get process id from SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION struct?

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn, win32gui

I am iterating on all the processes in the system using:

1. Get the first process using "NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buffer, buffer_size, NULL)".
2. Get the next processes using "NextEntryOffset" in SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION whose format is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess.

and I want to filter these processes based on their PID. How do I get the PID from SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION struct is not clear to me. There is a field called "UniqueProcessId" which gives a HANDLE to the process but after passing it to "GetProcessId" I get error code 6 which means process handle is not correct.

Any suggestions on finding either the process handle or pid from SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get definition of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION`? Different sources have different layout for that struct...

Comment: `UniqueProcessId` this is *PID* which you want get

Comment: @RbMm UniqueProcessId is of type "HANDLE" which is a void*. How do I get pid which is of type DWORD from this?

Comment: by cast. really process id and thread id is *HANDLE*. this is handles in special *PspCidTable*. win32 layer by some reason define it as *DWORD*. but all native api use it as *HANDLE* -look for *CLIENT_ID*. if want use process is in some win32 api - use *(ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)UniqueProcessId*

Comment: There is no point in using an undocumented api function when the [documented one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) trivially solves your problem.

Comment: [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the NT api will contain the following statement:

> [Nt*** may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows.]

In your case, you can use the following methods instead of `NtQuerySystemInformation` to retrieve the process of the system:

- [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) + [`Process32First`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32first)/[`Process32Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32next)
- [`EnumProcesses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses)
- [`WTSEnumerateProcesses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumerateprocessesa)
- [`WTSEnumerateProcessesEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumerateprocessesexa)(`WTS_ANY_SESSION`)

Comment: I want data regarding network I/O for the process. This data is available in SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION as part of "ReadTransferCount" and "WriteTransferCount". I could not find similar data on the handles returned by any of the above mentioned APIs.

Comment: [`GetProcessIoCounters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprocessiocounters) could useful to you. You could get the process id first, then `OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,0,processid)` to get the handle, finnally call `GetProcessIoCounters`.

Comment: In addition, you can also use WMI Class: [`Win32_Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process). "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process" to get all the instances of `Win32_Process` in system.